# Upper and lower bound of while loop

Tags: code-analysis, lower-bound

I am stuck on a question in a past paper for an embedded software course.

The question asks the following:

```
Let n be the number of iterations of the while loop. Calculate an upper and lower bound on the value of n given that b <= bmax.

x=a
if x<1
then 
  x=1
end if
while x<b
  loop
    x=x+1
  end
```

I think that the upper bound would be: n<=bmax but I don't understand how to calculate a lower bound. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the lower bound, you get that when a > 1. Then x starts at a instead of at 1, so you need fewer iterations to get from there to b.

If you start with x = a, and the last iteration happens when x = b (you fail the test), then you needed a total of b - a iterations. Since b <= bmax, the answer is:

```
lower bound : bmax - a
upper bound : bmax - 1
```

Note that if a >= bmax, the lower bound reduces to 0, as you cannot have fewer than 0 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Given only the information provided, the best you can do is the trivial lower bound - 0 iterations. This is because when `a>=b`, the loop won't execute at all.

As for the upper bound, you have an off by one error. Since `x` starts at a minimum of 1, you can have up to `bmax-1` iterations, not `bmax`.

Comment: I think you are oversimplifying the lower bound. Yes it might be as low as zero, but it can be expressed in terms of a

Comment: But a is unknown. You could also express the upperbound in terms of b, but since the problem gives you a bound on b in terms of the explicit constant bmax, the intent seems to be that your bounds are not in terms of a and b.

Comment: @Floris, in which case it will be bmax - a, for a >= 1.

Comment: @user268396 - this is what I stated in my answer... didn't think I needed to repeat it in my comment.

Comment: @Antimony - I don't think it's wrong to express in a, and say "this might be as low as zero". As I did in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is: b is some b <= bmax. Now express the number of iterations n, in terms of bmax and a. The lower bound on n is trivial, `0`, if `a >= bmax`; The upper bound on n is the case `a < 1`, which yields: `n = bmax - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
upper bound: max(0,b-1) <= max(0,bmax-1)

lower bound: if (a<1) then max(0,b-1), else max(0,b-a)
```

The lower bound cannot be expressed with bmax instead of b, because we have `b<=bmax`, not `bmax<=b`. If we are not allowed to use `b`, then it is `0`.